# Verifying $B - \bigcap\limits_{A \in \mathcal{A}} = \bigcup\limits_{A \in \mathcal{A}} B - A$ when $\mathcal{A}$ is the empty collection

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Suppose $\mathcal{A}$ is the empty collection. I claim that
$$B - \bigcap\limits_{A \in \mathcal{A}} A = \bigcup\limits_{A \in \mathcal{A}} (B - A).$$
Denote the set-theoretic universe by $\mathcal{U}$. By convention,
$$\bigcap\limits_{A \in \mathcal{A}} A = \mathcal{U}.$$
So for $x$ to live in $B - \bigcap\limits_{A \in \mathcal{A}}$ is to say that $x$ lives in $B - \mathcal{U}$. To live in $B$ requires living in $\mathcal{U}$, so the LHS is the empty set.

On the right-hand side, we have
$$x \in \bigcup\limits_{A \in \mathcal{A}} (B - A) \iff \exists A \in \mathcal{A}, \; x \in (B - A).$$
But since there do not exist $A \in \mathcal{A}$, the right-hand side is false for any $x \in \mathcal{U}$, so the RHS is also the empty set.

Is this correct?

Comment: That looks good to me.